# Reversing hash function in java

Tags: java

My first time posting.  Been getting into coding quite a bit lately.  I *thought* I completed another google foobar challenge, but when I verify this code with google I get errors 3/5 times (no feedback on the diagram's that sprung errors.)  I get no errors when I generate 10 million random diagrams...

Anyway, here is my code to reverse the hash (129*message[i] XOR message[0]) %256:

```
public static int[] answer(int[] digest){
    int[] message = new int[digest.length];
    message[0] = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < digest.length; i++){
        for(int n = 0; n < 256; n++){//find the possible inverses of mod 256...should figure out what to max n out at, 256*256?
            //the digest number and message number should be 1 apart.
            int modInverse = n*256+digest[i];//x mod y = z  if x = ny + z...find possible values of inverse mod 256
            int xorInverse = modInverse^message[i-1];//undo XOR using all of the tested modInverse and previous message...might need to do previous digest?
            int divided = xorInverse/129;//undo multiplying by 129.
            int remainder = xorInverse%129;//see if there is no remainder.
            if(remainder == 0){
                message[i] = divided;
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    return message;
}
```

Here is a link where someone actually posted the challenge: https://goo.gl/Tw4LpA

Comment: Hashes / digests are **not** reversible.

Comment: You may want to write a unit test using known inputs and and expected known output, then step through the code to figure out what's going wrong.